# How to use List as feature in scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mlp

I'd like to use **shape** feature as a **list** in sklearn, is it possible?
Using MLPClassifier

Given this input.

```
data=[{'forniture':1,'color':3, 'shape':[0.2,0.5,1.1]},
      {'forniture':2,'color':0, 'shape':[0.2,0.7,0.9]},
      {'forniture':2,'color':1, 'shape':[1.2,1.5,1.0]}]
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Exit

```
   forniture  color            shape
0          1      3  [0.2, 0.5, 1.1]
1          2      0  [0.2, 0.7, 0.9]
2          2      1  [1.2, 1.5, 1.0]
```

When I pass **shape** as argument in **clf.fit()**:
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

But I need the entire list, because it is the shape, I can not convert to scalar like Volume.

**Any recomendation to fit with the shape and not volume?**

Thanks, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Upon reading the documentation here:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.fit
It does not seem like it is possible to pass a list to the fit() function. Did you consider breaking up the list to three columns?
If so it is explained here:
[Split a Pandas column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/split-a-pandas-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was working with 3 diferent columns, but I thought it was going to be a good idea join them into a vector, list o matrix in order to improve the model. Because they are correlated data in real life.